# Can I correct grammar in questions/answers even if the message is clear?

Tags: discussion, editing, best-practices

I am talking about stuff like principle/principal, its/it's, your/you're, effect/affect.

Can I correct these things even though the meaning of the question/answer is clear?

Would it come across as rude, or as an "overkill"?

Comment: As a US English native speaker you may be used to [homonyms](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/homonym#Noun), but many other native speakers and [ESLers](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ESL#Noun) may not, and it can be very confusing for them if not corrected. Especially [*There* vs. *Their* vs. and *They're*](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-There,-Their-and-They%27re).

Comment: I am neither a US English speaker nor a native English speaker. But OK.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Even if it is by a small amount, corrections like these still improve the clarity of the post. However, I would encourage you to follow the advice of the [help page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), and look to see if there are any other problems you can correct while you are editing.

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23869/. Also it might be worth mentioning that some people will complain about edits anyway, possibly calling them rude or inappropriate or morally wrong - generally newer members who aren't familiar with how SE sites work.

Answer (score 13):

[Yes, please do](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit).  Such changes make the site easier to use for all readers.

Comment: What about *Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged*?

Comment: @BioPhysicist The linked help page explicitly supports fixing grammatical errors. My reading of the sentence you excerpt is that editors should fix all of a post's grammatical errors in one go, rather than in a string of one-character edits. You could plausibly argue that fixing a single "you'r" is a trivial edit, but I don't think you could argue against fixing four of them.